# bnx2 keep dropping packets

Tags: centos, nic

as mention, my Centos server nic keep dropping packet from time to time, (on-board Broadcom NetXtreme II) it drop packet on eth0 RX:

```
RX packets:4343890 errors:0 dropped:5705 overruns:0 frame:0
```

I read some post over internet and try, like

```
ethtool -C eth0 rx-usecs 8 rx-usecs-irq 8 rx-frames 0 rx-frames-irq 0
```

&

```
ethtool -G eth0 rx 1020
```

but no help

Any idea?

Thank you very much !!

Below is the output of eth0 statistic

```
 rx_bytes: 855190320
 rx_error_bytes: 0
 rx_ucast_packets: 3850326
 rx_mcast_packets: 436547
 rx_bcast_packets: 251196
 rx_crc_errors: 0
 rx_align_errors: 0
 rx_fragments: 0
 rx_jabbers: 0
 rx_undersize_packets: 0
 rx_oversize_packets: 0
 rx_64_byte_packets: 2684429
 rx_65_to_127_byte_packets: 1042457
 rx_128_to_255_byte_packets: 16981
 rx_256_to_511_byte_packets: 76097
 rx_512_to_1023_byte_packets: 641744
 rx_1024_to_1522_byte_packets: 76361
 rx_1523_to_9022_byte_packets: 0
 rx_xon_frames: 0
 rx_xoff_frames: 0
 rx_mac_ctrl_frames: 0
 rx_filtered_packets: 0
 rx_ftq_discards: 0
 rx_discards: 0
 rx_fw_discards: 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You're going in blind. You should first start with 'ethtool --statistics eth0'  (the output of this will depend very much on the driver).

Enlarging the ring-buffer may help... is this a particularly large subnet (lots of broadcast?)

I have seen similar situations where this had something to do with the irqbalance service -- turning it off preventing the issue. Not sure if this is still relevant.